# Is it possible to represent characters with integers?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$rowgp="select name,m3,dpsd,phc,jtk from 2sem3 where rno='$rno'";
$resultrow=mysql_query($rowgp);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultrow)){
   echo  $row['m3'] ." ". $row['oops'];
   $one = $row['m3'];
   $two = $row['oops']
}
```

In the above code the variable `$one` contains a character from a to d (those are the characters present in the field `m3`). If the char is 'a', it should take it as 1; if 'b' then 2 (c=3,d=4, and so on). How can I do it without using if or switch statements?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to avoid a conditional?

Comment: Change the data values in the database?

Comment: `$one = ord($row['m3']) - ord('a') + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lookup = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3, 'd'=>4);

$rowgp="select name,m3,dpsd,phc,jtk from 2sem3 where rno='$rno'";
$resultrow=mysql_query($rowgp);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultrow)){
echo  $row['m3'] ." ". $row['oops'];
$one = $lookup[$row['m3']];
$two = $row['oops']
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$chars = range('a', 'z');
$nums = array_flip($chars);
echo $nums[$one] + 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Could use [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)

```
echo (ord($row['m3']) - ord('a') + 1);
```